# Know the changelist number of a have revision of a file in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I have a file `example.pl`. It has 5 revisions. I use the command `p4 sync example#3` to `sync` the file to its 3rd revision. 
Now, I want to know the version number of that file at that revision.

Example:- I want to know the `version of the file at`#3 change. i.e. it has to display 10418

```
 p4 file log example.pl
    //dev/example.pl
    ... #5 change 10591 edit on 2015/01/27 by abc (ubinary) 'added verilog '
    ... #4 change 10468 edit on 2015/01/09 by abc (ubinary) 'added read me'
    ... #3 change 10418 edit on 2014/12/21 by abc (ubinary) 'added pdf and modified pdp'
    ... #2 change 9185 edit on 2014/11/27 by new user (ubinary) 'Added cells'
    ... #1 change 9170 add on 2014/11/26 by user100 (ubinary) 'Fixed the physicalDesign '
```

Comment: 10418 is a changelist number not a version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 p4 filelog filename#`p4 fstat filename | tail -n2 | awk '{print $3}' | sed -n 1p` | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $4}'
```

This helped me . It will directly return the version associated with the file

```
p4 fstat filename | tail -n2 | awk '{print $3}' | sed -n 1p
```

Returns the revision of the file from `haverev` under `p4 fstat filename` . 
Then this will be passed to `p4 file log filename#<RevisionNumber>` . This returns all the revision below the RevisionNumber for that file . Then from that I select the `4th field from the second line` which returns me the `version associated with the file` .
Example:-

```
p4 stat example.pl | tail -n2 | awk '{print $3}' | sed -n 1p   -> `2`
```

Then ,

```
p4 filelog filename#2 | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $4}' -> `9185`
```

Answer (score 4):

Do:

```
p4 files file#have
```

This will give you output like the following:

```
//stream/main/file#2 - edit change 4 (text)
```

If you want just the changelist number, do:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %change% files file#have
```

which will get you just:

```
4
```

Comment: I didn't know about the -F filter option, that seems really useful. Thanks!